# How to draw gradient color for a circle Arc in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have acheived the gradient color in Xamarin.Android using SweepGradient for arc and Now i trying to acheive the gradientcolor in Xamarin.iOS.And also am trying this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630653/apply-gradient-color-to-arc-created-with-uibezierpath) but still am getting like linear gradient. I except like this.
[My requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkTPH.png).

Anyone could provide idea or solution for this.?

Thanks,
Yuvaraj.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40209979/1801544

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534144/how-to-draw-a-gradient-arc-with-core-graphics-iphone maybe helpful